# getter not being called properly

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vue-component

I have a Vue component with up/down arrows for voting on a comment and I have the following getter in the script class:

```
    public get hasVotedUp(): boolean {
        console.log("== get hasVotedUp")
        ...
```

When the page loads that getter is called properly because of `:class="{ 'active-vote': hasVotedUp }"` in the template (I can see `== get hasVotedUp` in the console).
I have another function which gets called once someone votes up the comment:

```
    private voteUp(): void {
        console.log("== voteUp pressed!")
        if (this.hasVotedUp) {
        ...
```

And when someone presses Up `voteUp` does indeed get called (I can see `== voteUp pressed!` being logged in the console), but I don't see `== get hasVotedUp` in the console. Why?

Comment: Give us a minimal reproduction case. With no more code or explanation than you've given this should be working. Due note though that getters causing side effects is something of a no-no in general.

Comment: @JaredSmith but the `console.log` does seem to work when the page loads - I guess it's not forbidden but just an anti-pattern of having side-effects in getters. Or perhaps the browser forbids it once the page has fully loaded...?

Comment: Not likely it's more of a convention. Developers generally have an expectation that a property access will not cause spooky action at a distance but I seriously doubt there's any actual enforcement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a read of the documentation [Computed Caching vs Methods](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Caching-vs-Methods).

> computed properties are cached based on their reactive dependencies. A computed property will only re-evaluate when some of its reactive dependencies have changed.

You can try changing your computed getter to a method, which will determine whether it's because of the computed caching, as the method will run each time.

Comment: This seems to be it - I changed it from a getter to a method and it works as expected. I guess there's a lot more RTFM-ing to do...

Comment: But Op's pseudo code is not complete, how can you conclude it does not have reactive state?

Comment: @ABOS I hadn't looked into the state and perhaps it just works - all I looked at is if the getter is getting called (as a first step towards understanding the flow).

Comment: @ABOS Most likely scenario